# C# Updating mySQLDateTime Datatable

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable

I'm having trouble updating a mySQL database with a datatable.  I can do it with an INSERT statement, but the table fails the assignment when I insert a row with the error "Couldn't store <...> in date Column.  I have millions of records to insert and I thought this way might be faster.  I actually don't care about the time, just the date.

```
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = string.Format(@"server={0};userid={1};password={2};database={3};AllowZeroDatetime=True", srvr, user, pass, db);
        MySqlCommand cmnd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmnd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        cmnd.CommandText = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dateTest";
        cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmnd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE dateTest (date DATE, dateTime DATETIME)";
        cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        string myDate = "2014-04-19";
        string myDateTime = "2014-04-20 00:00:00";

        //this code works
        cmnd.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO dateTest(date, dateTime) VALUES('{0}', '{1}')", myDate, myDateTime);
        cmnd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from dateTest", con);
        MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(tbl);
        foreach (DataRow row1 in tbl.Rows)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", row1["date"], row1["dateTime"]));
            //returns: 4/19/2014 : 4/20/2014 12:00:00 AM
        }
        DataRow row2 = tbl.NewRow();
        row2["date"] = myDate; //Errors here: Couldn't store <2014-04-19> in date Column.  Expected type is MySqlDateTime.
        row2["dateTime"] = myDateTime; //Also errors here: Couldn't store <2014-04-20 00:00:00> in dateTime Column.  Expected type is MySqlDateTime.
        tbl.Rows.Add(row2);
        da.Update(tbl);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my first time trying to answer a question. Hope this help.

I think you have to convert the date to DateTime first before you can store it in mysql.

```
string myDateTime = "2014-04-20 00:00:00";
DateTime myDateTimeValue = DateTime.Parse(myDateTime);
```

Then

```
row2["dateTime"] = myDateTimeValue;
```

I have not tried it yet. Hope it works

Comment: I assume you mean `row2["dateTime"] = myDateTimeValue;`. It does not work. I get the error: "Couldn't store <4/20/2014 12:00:00 AM> in dateTime Column.  Expected type is MySqlDateTime.".  It converts it to a different format. I wonder if that has anything to do with it.